# What does `I` (uppercase i) mean in `ps aux`?

Tags: ps

In man page of `ps` under **Process State Codes**, the `I` flag (capital i) is not mentioned but `ps aux` shows the `I` flag in some processes as shown by the image below.

[image]

What does the **I** flag mean?

Comment: Please, DO NOT post pictures of text. Copying it out of terminal would have been much easier for both of us.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It means [“idle”](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/array.c#n135). This state was introduced [in version 4.14 of the Linux kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=06eb61844d841d0032a9950ce7f8e783ee49c0d0), in September 2017. It is used for kernel threads which use the `TASK_IDLE` state when idling, instead of `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`; in previous versions of the kernel, such threads were reported as `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` which was confusing.

`ps` reports this without needing any change itself, because it [reports the state directly from `/proc`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/proc/readproc.c).

Comment: What is the difference between those two states?

Comment: See [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=80ed87c8a9ca0cad7ca66cf3bbdfb17559a66dcf): uninterruptible tasks contribute to the load average, so idle kernel threads idled in interruptible state, but that caused some issues, so a new “no load” state was introduced, along with a helper “idle” state. The idle state was made reportable in the later patch linked in the answer. So basically “idle” is “uninterruptible” but doesn’t contribute to the load average.

Comment: Also see `htop` source code - https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/59166da773d8a9a97c8f1b087346865bc8cda9fa/linux/LinuxProcess.c#L163 `[STATE] = { .name = "STATE", .title = "S ", .description = "Process state (S sleeping, R running, D disk, Z zombie, T traced, W paging, I idle)", .flags = 0, }`