# I in the process status coloumn in top and total tasks > sleeping+running tasks

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, kali-linux, top

[image]

I ran top in kali linux 2018.1 and was unable to figure out a few things.

What does I stands for in the process status coloumn. I know about R,S,D,K,T and Z but don't have any idea about I.

Also while monitoring the with top it came to my notice that total task count is way more than sleeping+running taks count. Souldn't it be total=running+sleeping.

Thanks

Comment: `I` probably stands for "idle". The `top` manual should tell you this.

Comment: I have gone through the man page but 'I' was not there

Comment: I'm guessing, but you'll probably find that the number of idle tasks is the total number of tasks minus the number of sleeping tasks (i.e. 63).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`I` stands for “idle”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412471/86440).

Regarding the number of tasks, `top` shows the total number of tasks, and the numbers of running, sleeping, stopped, and zombie tasks. This ignores uninterruptible tasks and idle tasks, which should account for the difference. You can see the detailed counts by state with the following command:

```
ps -e -o state | sort | uniq -c
```